# here-document at line ... delimited by end-of-file (wanted `...')

Tags: linux, shell

I changed hosts and the script worked before but I had to change the server and port.

Here is the script:

```
echo "FTPing file..."
ftp -p -n -v my.server.com 8888 << EOT
user myusername mypassword
prompt
bin
put ${FILEDIR}.gz ${FILE}.gz
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

The error I am getting is such:

```
Backing up KB mysql database
Starting dump to file...
Dump complete...
Gzipping file...
Gzip complete...
/home2/myuser/backups/zips/mykb.sql.2017_02_08.gz was created:
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 126315 Feb  8 21:44 /home2/myuser/backups/zips/mykb.sql.2017_02_08.gz
FTPing file...
/home2/myuser/backups/backupkb.sh: line 46: warning: here-document at line 39 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOT')
ftp: connect: Connection refused
Not connected.
Interactive mode off.
Not connected.
Not connected.
```

I'm rather new to unix and this is a being run as a cron job on my shared rented web server so I really don't know what the error means.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The ["Here document"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) must be terminated with the same symbol it starts with. You start with `EOT`, but end with `END_SCRIPT`.

This is correct code:

```
echo "FTPing file..."
ftp -p -n -v my.server.com 8888 << EOT
user myusername mypassword
prompt
bin
put ${FILEDIR}.gz ${FILE}.gz
quit
EOT
exit 0
```

Comment: Ty for the response. I made the change but I'm getting this message `line 46: warning: here-document at line 39 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOT')`

Comment: For me its works OK. Show us your new script.